Unable to use Analog Devices libiio library using C language in VSC installed in Ubuntu
Good afternoon.
I'm a junior engineer just starting at a telecomm company. We're working with SDR devices, looking to automatize validation procedures using the libiio library.
But for two weeks now, we can't figure out how to get libiio working in a VSC environment for C language.
We work on miniPCs with Ubuntu OS.
First, we followed Analog Devices official installation steps found at text and text.
Then we got VSC ready by installing C/C++ and Code Runner extensions.
We learned that a C compiler is required, so we installed gcc.
We also learned about library paths, includes and such.
Also, i've seen that there are certain .json files that can be autogenerated by VSC, which you can later customize, but i've read in different sites different opinios saying that I need them, that I don't...
Also, we've spent a lot of time trying to solve it using chatGPT, but it reallly didn't provide solutions and enters loops asking to do the same things over and over.
Right now we have libiio.so saved at a directory which i've tried referencing when building the project with "gcc ad9361_stream.c -o ad9361_stream -L/path/to/.so_file -liio", but only results in "undefined reference to methods/functions"
I'm not sure what the problem is. We are using an example C script provided by analog devices "ad9361-iiostream.c", which you can find in the "examples" folder in github.
We made sure to have all the required headers in the workspace, as well as the .so file referenced when trying to build. We checked that libiio is installed...
Regardless of everything we've tried, we get errors like:
 /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccAWCaAL.o: in function `shutdown':
 ad9361-iiostream.c:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `iio_stream_destroy'
 /usr/bin/ld: ad9361-iiostream.c:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `iio_stream_destroy'
 /usr/bin/ld: ad9361-iiostream.c:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to `iio_channels_mask_destroy'
 /usr/bin/ld: ad9361-iiostream.c:(.text+0xf4): undefined reference to `iio_channels_mask_destroy'
 /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccAWCaAL.o: in function `handle_sig':
 ad9361-iiostream.c:(.text+0x155): undefined reference to `stop_stream'
 /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccAWCaAL.o: in function `wr_ch_lli':
 ad9361-iiostream.c:(.text+0x1e4): undefined reference to `iio_attr_write_longlong'
 /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccAWCaAL.o: in function `wr_ch_str':
 ad9361-iiostream.c:(.text+0x247): undefined reference to `iio_attr_write_string'
 /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccAWCaAL.o: in function `cfg_ad9361_streaming_ch':
 ad9361-iiostream.c:(.text+0x6ca): undefined reference to `iio_attr_write_string'
 /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccAWCaAL.o: in function `main':
 ad9361-iiostream.c:(.text+0x870): undefined reference to `iio_create_context'
 /usr/bin/ld: ad9361-iiostream.c:(.text+0x8d7): undefined reference to `iio_create_context'
 /usr/bin/ld: ad9361-iiostream.c:(.text+0xc16): undefined reference to `iio_create_channels_mask'
 /usr/bin/ld: ad9361-iiostream.c:(.text+0xc67): undefined reference to `iio_create_channels_mask'
 /usr/bin/ld: ad9361-iiostream.c:(.text+0xe0c): undefined reference to `iio_context_get_params'
 /usr/bin/ld: ad9361-iiostream.c:(.text+0xe40): undefined reference to `iio_prm_printf'

If someone experienced in C development environment setups with external libraries, dependencies and compilers can help, we would be eternally grateful
I've tried to install the libiio library using every resource I found, in official and unofficial sources. I expected to find the way to use this library to control via IP communication a SDR chip

Do not use CodeRunner. It is only suitable for toy programs. Also learn the difference between -L and -l, you likely need both. See this for more info.

I finally found the way to make the library work.
I'll just share here what solved the issue for me, which wasn't any kind of complex solution.
I realized I had filled the miniPC with different libiio versions, libraries, compilers, programs and files.
Finding it difficult to see clearly what I was referencing at any time, what I was using to debug and compile, what headers I was using, I decided to start a new installation from scratch in a virtual machine in my Windows PC.
I installed Ubuntu from a iso file "ubuntu-24.04.1-desktop-amd64" in VirtualBox, and just followed the instructions found in [https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-software/libiio] for Debian based distributions and the "Remaining steps1"
Also mention that I needed to create a tasks.json file for the C script to be able to compile and link the libraries. Afterwards, I just used Ctrl + Shift + B to compile.
Mi issue, which was simply to make the library work, was solved with this. I realize that probably I made it more difficult for myself due to my lack of practice programming, but I hope at least this might help somebody.
Thanks to the people who answered.
